# Steps to Boot Linux from USB on Windows 10/Linux Dual Install

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, mbr

I'm interested in a high-level view of booting Linux from a partition separate from Windows using a USB bootloader.

My work computer must have Windows 10 on it because of company policy.  IT is hesitant to allow a dual boot since there are [several](https://medium.com/@petragospodneti/windows-10-and-linux-love-hate-dual-boot-problems-d9994cbe16c0) [potential](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install-insiderplat_pc/updating-windows-10-while-dual-booting-linux/6fcd2627-dfdc-4ac3-9260-e4de51e8d539) [problems](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-update-error-0x800703ed-dual-boot-with/c55815b7-2931-4cd2-a40b-08843f7072b2).  They have instead approved use of a persistent USB Linux.  However, I'm concerned about the integrity of this.

It seems the root problems with dual boot come from a shared MBR.  If so, the problem ought to be overcome by, effectively, having separate MBRs.

- How might I go about installing Linux on a SSD partition and booting from USB?
- What problems can I anticipate?
- Is this a fool's errand?

It seems like the process would go something like,

1. Use Windows to create a new partition
2. Install Linux on the partition *without* an MBR
3. [Format and install GRUB on a USB](http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:boot:usb)
4. Configure GRUB to point to either the Windows install or the Linux install
5. Configure the BIOS to boot from USB first

Comment: Have you considered virtual-box.  I had lots of problems with IT support at work: Delays in approving stuff for instillation, etc. So I put is a request for Virtual-box, it took twice as long as any other request, but once installed, I never asked for anything else again. I just installed Debian, and everything else I needed.

Comment: Yes, I have, thank you.  That's a reasonable suggestion.  Yet it seems that working from a VM always has a problem, from mouse integration despite guest additions, or 100% CPU usage within the VM on common operations with `apt`, to corrupted guest images when closing the host laptop lid.  I've also used Cygwin, MSYS2, and MinGW yet have to jump through Windows related hoops, seemingly inevitably, despite all claims otherwise.  Things Just Work™ with bare metal.  The closer I can get to that, the happier I'll be.

Comment: FWIW I had success with VMWare-10 on Win-7 in a highly restrictive corporate environment - once I had found the VMWare-10 binary and licence on our directory of pre-approved apps, I was away (I choose Fedora and client). Never looked back, never had the problems that you outline. Only inconvenience was I still had to use Outlook but copy-paste and file transfer between client and host made it pretty easy.

Comment: That said, I _think_ your plan for a USB MBR sounds doable.

Comment: @wef My experience with virtualization on Windows is only with VirtualBox.  Is it VMware Workstation you're referring to?

Comment: Yes - VMWare Workstation 10 was the one I could get a corporate licence for. There are more up to date versions around but that was fine for Window-7 host and Fedora-24 client. There may be ready-rolled, free fedora images for VMWare Workstation around - try googling for them - it might avoid the need for a licence.

Comment: The definition and understanding of *dual-boot* is somewhat obfuscated.  The simple way is to `F11` from BIOS to get a boot menu *at that point in boot process* and then select either (a) your company windows 10 disk, or (b) you linux on whatever piece of storage.  This way you can leave your win10 company disk untouched.

Comment: Yes there are problems messing with the Windows 10 boot partition simply don't do it;  have BIOS point to GRUB on separate disk/usb_stick and boot that; then GRUB will menu prompt `boot your win10 disk` or `boot linux disk`.  You basically install CentOS_7 on disk2, `grub2-mkconfig` and it automatically recognizes win10 on disk1 and creates a menu entry.  I do this at home, always boot grub on my linux ssd and then menu select via grub what to boot, I default to my win10_home disk.  Any linux using grub2 will likely do the same.

Comment: you can basically do all this without the support or IT or permission from anyone, as long as you can F2 or DEL into the BIOS settings, just tell it to boot `whatever` instead of the existing win10 disk.